# ${\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{x} \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-x} \cdot \left(1-\dfrac{1}{x} \right) \mathrm dx}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>
> $$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left\{\dfrac{1}{x}\right\} \cdot \left\{\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right\} \cdot \left\{1-\dfrac{1}{x} \right\} \mathrm dx$$
>
> where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: Question is incomplete. With respect to what variable are you integrating?

Comment: It is a rational function of $x$ so you should find the partial fraction decomposition. It is undefined at the endpoints of the integral so you must take that into consideration.

Comment: There was fractional part of factors but Plato removed it in edit.

Comment: Try just simplifying the expression algebraically.

Comment: The integrand can be simplified to $\frac{-1}{x^2}$

Comment: Please edit your title to match your body or vice versa. The title question is much, much easier than the body one.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those problems where it seems like there's only really one way we can start, but it ends up looking intractable. I'll offer what I can; maybe someone can spot how to evaluate this in closed form (or rigorously prove it's not doable), or efficiently do a numerical estimate.

Set $y=1/x,\,z=y-n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ so the integral is$$\int_1^\infty\{y\}(1-\{y\})\{\tfrac{1}{y-1}\}\tfrac{dy}{y^2}=\sum_{n\ge1}I_n,\,I_n:=\int_0^1z(1-z)\{\tfrac{1}{z+n-1}\}\tfrac{dz}{(z+n)^2}.$$With $u=\tfrac1z$,$$I_1=\int_1^\infty\tfrac1u(1-\tfrac1u)\{u\}\tfrac{du}{(u+1)^2}=\sum_{m\ge1}J_m,\,J_m:=\int_m^{m+1}\tfrac1u(1-\tfrac1u)(u-m)\tfrac{du}{(u+1)^2}.$$[In fact](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281-u%29*%28u%2Bm%29%2F%28u%5E2%2Bu%29%5E2+from+m+to+m%2B1&dataset=)$$J_m=\int_m^{m+1}\tfrac{(1-u)(u+m)}{u^2(u+1)^2}du=\tfrac{6}{m+2}-\tfrac{3}{m+1}+(2-6m)\ln(m+1)+(3m-1)\ln(m(m+2)).$$[For $n\ge2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%281-z%29%2F%28%28z%2Bn%29%5E2%28z%2Bn-1%29%29+as+partial+fractions),$$I_n=\int_0^1(\tfrac{n-n^2}{z+n-1}+\tfrac{n^2-n-1}{z+n}+\tfrac{n^2+n}{(z+n)^2})dz=(n-n^2)\ln\tfrac{n^2}{n^2-1}-\ln\tfrac{n+1}{n}+1.$$So the original integral is$$\begin{align}I&:=\sum_{m\ge1}(\tfrac{6}{m+2}-\tfrac{3}{m+1}+(2-6m)\ln(m+1)+(3m-1)\ln(m(m+2)))\\&+\sum_{n\ge2}((n-n^2)\ln\tfrac{n^2}{n^2-1}-\ln\tfrac{n+1}{n}+1).\end{align}$$You'll want to double-check I didn't make any mistakes in this, mind.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\{1 - \frac{1}{x}\} = \{-\frac{1}{x}\} = 1 - \{\frac{1}{x}\}$, we have
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^1 \{\tfrac{1}{x}\}\{\tfrac{1}{1-x}\} (1 - \{\tfrac{1}{x}\})\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 \{\tfrac{1}{x}\}\{\tfrac{1}{1-x}\} \mathrm{d}x
- \int_0^1 \{\tfrac{1}{x}\}^2\{\tfrac{1}{1-x}\} \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}

From 2.10 and 2.12 (page 101) in [1], we have
$$\int_0^1 \{\tfrac{1}{x}\}\{\tfrac{1}{1-x}\} \mathrm{d}x = 2\gamma - 1$$
and
$$\int_0^1 \{\tfrac{1}{x}\}^2\{\tfrac{1}{1-x}\} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{5}{2} - \gamma - \ln (2\pi)$$
where $\gamma $ is Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Thus, we have $I = 3\gamma - \frac{7}{2} + \ln (2\pi) \approx 0.069524062$.

Also, I approximated the integral numerically in Maple which resembles the analytic result above.

*Reference*:

[1] Ovidiu Furdui, "Limits, Series, and Fractional Part Integrals: Problems in Mathematical Analysis".